# javascript get value of paragraph to appear in textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the value of a paragraph to a text area using javascript. This is my code at the moment. I can't quite seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated

```
  <html>
  <head>
   </head>
  <body>
  <button value="this is a length definition" onclick="reveal(this.value)"> hi</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function reveal(value)
  {
  var text = value;
  document.outputtext.value += value;
  }
  </script>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><textarea name="outputtext"></textarea></td>
  </tr></table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your textarea is not part of the document. Also your button value is not a paragraph.

- Give it an ID and use `document.getElementById("outputtext").value` (recommended) or
- wrap in a form and do `document.formName.outputtext.value` or
- use the clumsy `document.getElementsByName("outputtext")[0].value`

Here is the code using ID

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/b6WrF/)

```
  <html>
  <head>
   </head>
  <body>
  <button value="this is a length definition" onclick="reveal(this.value)"> hi</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function reveal(value) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext").value += value;
  }
  </script>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><textarea id="outputtext"></textarea></td>
  </tr></table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

shoud change to

```
<textarea id="outputtext"></textarea>
```

then code change to

```
document.getElementById('outputtext')
```

good luck

You can use name but you have to call getElemntsByName() and receive an array of element

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button value="this is a length definition" onclick="reveal(this.value)"> hi</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reveal(value)
{
  var text = value;
  document.getElementById("outputtext").value += text;
}
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea id="outputtext"></textarea></td>
  </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code change to:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
<button value="this is a length definition" onclick="reveal(this.value);"> hi</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reveal(value)
     document.getElementById("outputtext").value += value;
 }
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea id="outputtext"></textarea></td>
  </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe we already answered this a while ago... Nothing new